# Image analysis and classification of multiple objects in one picture

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

Im working on a project to automate some image analysis from microscope images. What I want to achieve is to classify the gray structures as one class, and the black ones as another, and then collor them in some other collor. I also want the program to calculate the area of these. Do you have any tips on algorithms for this?

Regards, David

Comment: This description is way too vague to get an answer.

Comment: This is a very vague description of your problem... Maybe look into [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing))